# How to add object at the beginning of the list in ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

ArrayAdapter has method `add(T object)` which add an object at the end of a list.
Is there a way to add object at the beginning of the list?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use the [`.insert(T object, int index)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert(T,%20int)) method for this, using `0` as an index:

```
yourAdapter.insert(object, 0);
```

Comment: it's work but when I use this method it's also scroll my listview to top. For example my listview is at position 0, I add 5 elements before (at position 0) and my listview scrolls at position 0, but it shoud stay at last selected position (6)

Comment: You need to do that manually. It re-inflates the list from scratch, so this will be an expected side-effect.

Comment: @krinn You may such a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597450/android-listview-add-items-to-top-without-list-view-scroll to retain the scroll position

Comment: can we have anything for List class object? As currently we add in apter like this `adapter.addAll(messageList);` so there is any way to set list at the top of the listview?