# Android ListView add items to top without list view scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a listView and I want to add new items to the top of the list view but I dont want list view to scroll its content. I want user to look at the same item as he was looking before new items were added.

This is how I add new items to ListView:

```
this.commentsListViewAdapter.addRangeToTop(comments);
this.commentsListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and this is `addRangeToTop` method:

```
public void addRangeToTop(ArrayList<Comment> comments)
{
    for (Comment comment : comments)
    {
        this.insert(comment, 0);        
    }
}
```

this is my listView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/CommentsListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/AddCommentLayout" 
    android:stackFromBottom="true" >        
</ListView>
```

What I want to do is to load old comments when user scrolls to the top.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have found solution here [Retaining position in ListView after calling notifyDataSetChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276128/retaining-position-in-listview-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged)

Sorry for duplicate question.
The final code is this:

```
    int index = this.commentsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + comments.size();
    View v = this.commentsListView.getChildAt(commentsListView.getHeaderViewsCount());
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();         

    this.commentsListViewAdapter.AddRangeToTop(comments);
    this.commentsListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    

    this.commentsListView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Answer (score 9):

May be this is what you are looking for:

```
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```

"This makes list automatically scroll to the bottom when a data set change notification is received and only if the last item is already visible on screen." - as quoted [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode)

Comment: this answer should be marked correct.

Comment: For recyclerview the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/43647835/4204668

Answer (score 3):

Also have a look at ListView's method `public void setSelection (int position)`. After you added new comments, and notified your adapter, you can use it to keep the current item selected.

```
// Get the current selected index
int previousSelectedIndex = yourListView.getSelectedItemPosition();

// Change your adapter
this.commentsListViewAdapter.AddRangeToTop(comments);
this.commentsListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


// Determine how many elements you just inserted
int numberOfInsertedItems = comments.size();

// Update the selected position
yourListView.setSelection(previousSelectedIndex + numberOfInsertedItems);
```

NOTE: Code is untested. Good luck

Comment: thank you, this works somehow, but not very well. It scrolls two items up. I think it is because List view does not scroll by items but by pixels, and setSelection scrolls exactly to the item.