# How to add object at the beginning of the list in ArrayAdapter if the object is different data type?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I just check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000217/how-to-add-object-at-the-beginning-of-the-list-in-arrayadapter) link to add an object at the top of the adapter.

Here is the code which I found that to add an object to at the top of the adapter:

```
yourAdapter.insert(object, 0);
```

But in my case the data type of object is different from the data type of adapter. So I am getting following error:

***Wrong 1st argument type. required.......***

So I decided to cast the object and then try to insert:

```
adapter.insert((OneOnOneMessage)messageList, 0);
```

But no luck was with me and started getting following run time error:

```
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.mics.models.OneOnOneMessage
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at com.mics.activities.SingleChatActivity$2.onClick(SingleChatActivity.java:283)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4448)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18461)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
03-08 14:55:43.933 6358-6358/com.dayoptions.chat W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can add an object into the adapter by using following code:

```
adapter.addAll(messageList);
```

Using above line I am not getting any issue regarding `'wrong argument type'` or `'casting'` but I want to add the object at the top of the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

Created new List and fetched new messages into this:

```
messageListLoad = OneOnOneMessage.loadEarlierMessages(sessionData.getId(), buddyId, messageList.get(0).getId(), LOAD_EARLIER_COUNT);
```

Load new created list into the previous list using following code:

```
for (int i = messageListLoad.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   messageList.add(0, messageListLoad.get(i));
}
```

And at the end tells the adapter we have some new values in the list:

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't cast a **list(messageList)** to an object of type **OneOnOneMessage**.

you can cast a single item from the list like this:

```
adapter.insert((OneOnOneMessage)messageList.get(index), 0);
```

Comment: Thank yo for the suggestion but I solved my problem in a different way. I am not approving your answer but for a valid suggestion, I am upvoting your answer.

Comment: no problem, would you please share your solution, Thanks